# Make a GET web request from Powershell that includes a body

Tags: rest, powershell, elasticsearch

I'm trying to query Elasticsearch from PowerShell using `Invoke-WebRequest`. Elasticsearch requires that the GET request have a body which `iwr` forbids. Is there a workaround or something? Maybe some other program that allows this? `curl` on POSIX allows this. I know it's not standard, but take it up with Elasticsearch.

Here's what I tried:

```
Invoke-WebRequest http://localhost:9200/index* -Body '{
    "size": 1,
    "sort": [
        { "timestamp": {"order": "asc"}}
    ],
    "query": {
        <query here>
    }
}' -Method GET
```

This returned:
`Invoke-WebRequest : Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.`

Thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem with my GET command when creating a Powershell GUI for my HTPC. I ended up running through this http://thesociablegeek.com/azure/using-curl-in-powershell/

It has made it so much easier to run GET commands. Keep in mind, use double quotations instead of single otherwise it errors out.

Also some simple tips that I overlooked, Spaces to %20 and convert the response from JSON (if wanted).

Comment: Good tip, thanks. Though at that point I'd probably use bash on windows...the hope was to just get this working with Powershell. Ridiculous that Powershell artificially limits queries like this.

Comment: `Invoke-RestMethod` also errors with `Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type.` Any suggestions?

Comment: curl on posix doesn't apprently doesn't allow that (how could it? the server answers a get without listening for a body), it [uses post.](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/11211)